# get millisecond to display in android decive

Tags: java, android, milliseconds

Here is my code.

```
int hours = (int) (timeElapsed / 3600000);
int minutes = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
int seconds = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;
```

I need to now calculate MilliSeconds that runs really fast.

Please help me how?

Comment: I just thought I'd mention that division runs relatively slowly on most devices compared to addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

One way to speed up things is to minimize the run-time mathematical operations by reusing some of the intermediate calculations. Adding some constants, whose calculation is done at compile-time, will increase readability. Assuming timeElapsed is an int, you can also remove the casting.

```
    final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    final int MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60 * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    final int MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR = 60 * MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    int hours = timeElapsed / MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
    timeElapsed -= hours * MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;

    int minutes = timeElapsed / MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
    timeElapsed -= minutes * MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    int seconds = timeElapsed / MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    timeElapsed -= seconds * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;

    int millis = timeElapsed;
```

The last two lines could be combined for a bit more speed, but the symmetry looked nice.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing logic, try this.

```
int millis = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000 - 
                    minutes * 60000 - seconds * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not incredibly fast, but you can do
    int millis = timeElapsed %1000; 
If you're looking for a simple calculation. It might run faster if an optimizer realized it's not dependent on the previous variables. That being said, modulo is an expensive operation compared to addition, multiplication, and subtraction.

Comment: Did this from my phone. Can somebody please fix formatting if they have a second? That our I can when I reach a computer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not really fast... it runs like a second.. and btw I only need 2 digit for millisecond.. it goes from 1 digit to 2 to 3 to 4 and soo on...

Comment: If it is acceptable to ruin that fast and you only want two digits, just tack /10 on the end and it should get you what you want. If that's not fast enough, I will brainstorm.

Answer (score 0):

```
int(millis() / 3600000); //HORAS - H

int((millis() % 3600000) / 60000); //MINUTOS - M

int(((millis() % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000); //SEGUNDOS - S

int(((millis() % 3600000) % 60000) % 1000); //MILESIMAS SEGUNDO - MS
```

:)