# How to get the starting time of an app in android

Tags: android, time

I create an android application, i have to create a notification about apps running in background with there staring time, i'll successfully get the running apps but cant generate that the app is running from how long time. For example-> Talking Tom is running from last 3 hours etc.

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {

```
// List context
private final Context context;

// List values
private final List<RunningAppProcessInfo> values;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<RunningAppProcessInfo> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

/**
 * Constructing list element view
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    long re = MainActivity.recived;
    long sd = MainActivity.send;
    System.out.println("hii");
    long po=MainActivity.pos;
/*    if(position!=po)
        return null;   */
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

    TextView appName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.appNameText);
    appName.setText(values.get(position).processName);

    TextView sendtxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sendtv);
    sendtxt.setText(String.valueOf(re/1024));

  //  sendtxt.setText(b1.getString("passed2"));
    TextView receivetxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.receivetv);
    receivetxt.setText(String.valueOf(sd/1024));

  //  receivetxt.setText(b1.getString("passed1"));

    return rowView;

}
```

}

MY SECOND CLASS IS:->

public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
 private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     //   get time value of all the processes (in Milliseconds)     

   long millisSinceBoot = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    long time = ((millisSinceBoot - values.get(position).activeSince)/1000); 
    //Log.i("HRHHRHRHRHR", "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+time);
    String time1 = String.valueOf(time);
    time_list.add(time);
    int seconds = (int) (time / 1000) % 60 ;
    int minutes = (int) ((time / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours   = (int) ((time / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    String time11 = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
    Log.i("Time", "Secs:- "+seconds+" "+"Mins:- "+minutes+" "+"Hours:- "+hours);
    timer.setText(time1);
```

Comment: But this will not show the correct time. It will show time in milliseconds and that is also wrong

Comment: Can anybody tell me, how can i find starting time of app of that day only....means app start today, so for today starting time of the app.......How can i do dis ?

Comment: You would have gotten a quicker response if you'd asked a new question. It's unlikely that many will notice your question buried down in some comments. But check out my answer to the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237587/get-millisecond-to-display-in-android-decive/22239446#22239446 . I think it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not correct one what i need

Comment: It was meant to show how to break down a millisecond interval into its constituent parts. Did you want something different?

Comment: Yup, I had a transcription error; I'd left in some code that made it return the wrong value. I also added in a human readable date string since the next person with this question might want it.

Comment: I want when i start my app, in app i set a notification which show app running time, like if i run my app like whatsapp at 11am, then at 2 pm it show a notification that whatsapp is run from 3 hours.

Comment: So just run the update code I provided and select out your app.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

You can get a list of each service's start time using ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.activeSince, described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#activeSince). Here's a snippet that retrieves the times for up all service processes.

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

 long currentMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();        
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
     cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis-info.activeSince);

     Log.i(TAG, String.format("Process %s with component %s has been running since %s (%d milliseconds)",
             info.process, info.service.getClassName(), cal.getTime().toString(), info.activeSince));
 }
```

Comment: What part are you unclear about? You can drop this code into your project and get a list of all the running background services. The included log statement will output the process name, service name, and run time (in seconds).

Comment: This time is not set in my List. It is correctly shown in logcat, but did'nt set in List. In a list it will show same time for all apps.  Can you tell me how can i set it.

Comment: im using map to fetch individually time with thier peocess name?    CAn u tell me how can i set in a list

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code for your list. But you should really post that as a separate question so that it'll get more attention (and likely better/quicker answers than I can provide). You can post a link to the new question here for reference.

Comment: Upto this, Code is successfully run.  Thankx for your concern

Comment: Now further list of my applications show same at every time, how to get updated list every time in new notification ?????